# Python - Seaborn "Dodged" Barch Chart from Dataframe

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot a dodged bar chart with Seaborn from the following Dataframe called 'airlines':

```
    Airline_Name    Count   Total_Negative_Reviews  Total_Neutral_Reviews   Total_Positive_Reviews
0   American        2604    1864                    433                     307
1   Delta           2222    955                     723                     544
2   Southwest       2420    1186                    664                     570
3   US Airways      2913    2263                    381                     269
4   United          3822    2633                    697                     492
5   Virgin America  504     181                     171                     152
```

My goal is to have a total of 4 bars for each airline: one for the total amount of reviews, one for the negative, another for the neutral, and other for the positive.

So far I can plot a chart with the total amount (as per below), but I can't seem to figure out how to add the other 3.

The code I already have (and its vizualisation):

```
sns.barplot(data = airlines, x = airlines["Airline_Name"], y = airlines["Count"])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGlqf.png)

Can somebody help me with this issue, please?

Answer (score 4):

Small preprocessing with [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) is required to make such a plot in `seaborn`:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars='Airline_Name', var_name='variable', value_name='values')
sns.barplot(x='Airline_Name',y='value',hue='variable',data=df1)
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

If plotting with `pandas` is an option, you can get the desired plot with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#df = pd.read_csv('airline.csv')
df.plot.bar(x='Airline_Name',stacked=False,subplots=False, figsize=(12,7))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Output**:[image]

If you want to have `seaborn` style with `pandas` plot, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
#df = pd.read_csv('airline.csv')

#if you want a stacked bar plot, keep stacked=True
df.plot.bar(x='Airline_Name',stacked=False,subplots=False, figsize=(12,7))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data will likely be best depicted by a stacked bar chart (either horizontally or vertically).

I did this quick and dirty using matplotlib, but the concept would be similar with seaborn as it's heavily based on matplotlib. The concept is that you're setting rectangles on top of each other. There may be other ways to do this with other libraries (e.g. Plotly, Bokeh, Altair, Vega, etc.), so please don't take this answer as gospel.

You could also do this directly using a grouped DataFrame via pandas, but I was crunched for time and hopefully someone else can add that answer to this particular thread.

The code to accomplish what you'd like is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# convert the columns to a numpy array
a_count = airlines['Count'].to_list()
a_neg = np.array(airlines['Total_Negative_Reviews'].to_list())
a_neut = np.array(airlines['Total_Neutral_Reviews'].to_list())
a_pos = np.array(airlines['Total_Positive_Reviews'].to_list())
a_name = airlines['Airline_Name'].to_list()

# set the width of the bars
width = 0.5

# create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(a_name, a_neg, width, label="Negative")
ax.bar(a_name, a_neut, width, bottom=a_neg, label='Neutral')
ax.bar(a_name, a_pos, width, bottom=a_neg+a_neut, label='Positive')


ax.legend()
ax.set_ylabel('# of Reviews')
ax.set_xlabel('Airline')
plt.show()
```

This will result in this chart:

[image: Matplotlib Stacked Bar Chart]